# The buttons in calculator are not working properly java

Tags: java

```
private void equalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
      double radian = StrictMath.toRadians(a);
        if (evt.getSource()== equal)
       {


           if (multiply == true)
           {
           b = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
           display.setText(Double.toString(a*b));
           }
           else if (plus == true)
           {
           b = Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
           display.setText(Double.toString(a+b));
           }
           else if (bsin == true)
           { 
               b= (StrictMath.sin(radian));
               display.setText(("Sin ("+a+") ="+b));      
           }

           else if(bfact = true)
           {
           b = factorial(a);
           display.setText(a+" ! = "+b); 
           }
            else if (btan == true)
           { 
               b= (StrictMath.tan(radian));
               display.setText(("tan ("+a+") ="+b));    
           }
       }  
    }
```

This is my code, for a few key of the calculator but the buttons are not working properly. When I press the sin key, it sometimes calculates the factorial and sometime sine, i can't understand its logic! can any body help me please!

Comment: Type caused by using `=` instead  of `==` in `bsin == true`, as `bsin` is `boolean` it's better to use `else if(bsin)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed "=" operator in your else if:

```
else if(bfact = true)
       {
       b = factorial(a);
       display.setText(a+" ! = "+b); 
       }
```

it must be:

```
 else if(bfact == true)
       {
       b = factorial(a);
       display.setText(a+" ! = "+b); 
       }
```

Comment: It's best if he doesn't say `if(something == true)`. Better to write `if(something)`.

Comment: change `if (evt.getSource()== equal)` to `if (evt.getSource().eaquls(ur value);`

Comment: thanx, now it works fine...:)